# How can I change rownames of dataframes in a list adding their own list names in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I try to change `row.names` of each dataframe in a list by adding their names to rownames.

`List` is:

```
l <- list(a=data.frame(col = c(1,2,3),row.names = c("k","l","m")), b=data.frame(col = 
c(4,5,6), row.names = c("o","p","r")))
```

I tried this but couldn't add index names `a` and `b`:

```
lapply(l,function(x) {x %>% `row.names<-` (paste(names(l)[which(l %in% 
x)],rownames(x),sep = "."))})
```

`l$a` is:

| row.names | col |
| --- | --- |
| k | 1 |
| l | 2 |
| m | 3 |

But it should be like this:

| row.names | col |
| --- | --- |
| a.k | 1 |
| a.l | 2 |
| a.m | 3 |

What should I do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the list, we can iterate over the name of the list, which can have better control when pasting the names together.

This is modified from your attempt:

```
setNames(lapply(names(l), 
                \(x) l[[x]] %>% `row.names<-` (paste(x, rownames(l[[x]]), sep = "."))), 
         names(l))

$a
    col
a.k   1
a.l   2
a.m   3

$b
    col
b.o   4
b.p   5
b.r   6
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `mapply`

```
mapply(function(lis, nm){rownames(lis) <- paste0(nm, ".", rownames(lis))
    list(lis)},
  dlis, names(dlis))
$a
    col
a.k   1
a.l   2
a.m   3

$b
    col
b.o   4
b.p   5
b.r   6
```

##### Data

```
dlis <- list(a = structure(list(col = c(1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("k",
"l", "m")), b = structure(list(col = c(4, 5, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("o",
"p", "r")))
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) rbind**  Use `rbind` to create a single data frame with the desired row names and then split it back to the original.

```
split(do.call("rbind", l), rep(names(l), sapply(l, nrow)))
```

**2) data.frame** Use `data.frame` and its `row.names=` argument to avoid `row.names<-`

```
rnames <- function(x, nm) data.frame(x, row.names = paste0(nm, ".", rownames(x)))
Map(rnames, l, names(l))
```

**3) for** Use a for loop creating `ll`

```
ll <- l
for(nm in names(ll)) rownames(ll[[nm]]) <- paste0(nm, ".", rownames(ll[[nm]]))
```