# row.names(x) versus row.names<- in lapply on a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, lapply, r-rownames

When I'm attempting to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75125313/how-can-i-change-rownames-of-dataframes-in-a-list-adding-their-own-list-names-in/75125557#75125557), I noticed that `row.names(x) <- vector` is not working when using `lapply` on a list of data frames, while `row.names<-` worked.

Here's some sample data, I'm attempting to append the `names` of the list to the `rownames` of the dataframes:

```
l <- list(a=data.frame(col = c(1,2,3),row.names = c("k","l","m")), 
          b=data.frame(col = c(4,5,6), row.names = c("o","p","r")))

$a
  col
k   1
l   2
m   3

$b
  col
o   4
p   5
r   6
```

For example when looping over the `names` of the list and setting `row.names` in `lapply`, this is the result:

```
lapply(names(l), \(x) row.names(l[[x]]) <- paste0(x, ".", rownames(l[[x]])))

[[1]]
[1] "a.k" "a.l" "a.m"

[[2]]
[1] "b.o" "b.p" "b.r"
```

When we do the same code outside `lapply`, it worked:

```
> row.names(l[["a"]]) <- paste0("a.", rownames(l[["a"]]))
> l

$a
    col
a.k   1
a.l   2
a.m   3
```

The solution I have for this problem is to use `row.names<-` (as suggested by the original OP):

```
setNames(lapply(names(l), 
                \(x) l[[x]] %>% `row.names<-` (paste(x, rownames(l[[x]]), sep = "."))), 
         names(l))

$a
    col
a.k   1
a.l   2
a.m   3

$b
    col
b.o   4
b.p   5
b.r   6
```

But I'm not sure why did the `row.names(x) <- vector` syntax failed and why `row.names<-` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The assignment is *local*, i.e. it creates a **modified** object `l` with assigned row names *inside* the anonymous function.
- The *result* of the `<-` assignment is returned from that anonymous function. However, the result of `<-` is *always* the RHS, even for replacement functions. You can make this visible by putting parentheses around the assignment in the global scope:

  ```
  (row.names(l$a) <- paste0('a.', row.names(l$a)))
  # [1] "a.k" "a.l" "a.m"
  ```

So in your second piece of code, the the transformation used by `lapply` is just the result of the assignment, which is the RHS of the assignment, which is the transformed row names. To fix the code, you need to return the modified object, `l[[x]]`, itself:

```
lapply(
    names(l),
    \(x) {
        row.names(l[[x]]) <- paste0(x, ".", row.names(l[[x]]))
        l[[x]]
    }
)
```

Or you use `row.names<-` as a function call:

```
lapply(names(l), \(x) `row.names<-`(l[[x]], paste0(x, ".", row.names(l[[x]]))))
```

And to make this a bit more readable use `Map` instead of `lapply`:

```
Map(\(x, n) `row.names<-`(x, paste0(n, ".", row.names(x))), l, names(l))
```

Or, without anonymous function (although I’m not convinced this is more readable):

```
Map(`row.names<-`, l, Map(paste0, names(l), ".", Map(row.names, l)))
```

Comment: Can I say that the most prominent difference between `row.names<-(df, vec)` and `row.names(x) <- vec` is that the former returns a renamed data frame while the latter primarily returns the vector?

Comment: @benson23 Yes, that is exactly right. Internally, the second version calls the replacement function, then assigns the result of that to the object named by its first argument, and then (invisibly) returns the vector.